# ajax POST call duplicates if there's more than one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I haave really weird problem, and i can't understand what's wrong with it.

HTML code:

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-selfid="{$id}"  data-filter="XO" data-placement='left'> Item 1</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
        $('*[data-selfid]').mouseenter(function(event) {
            var e=$(this);
            e.popover({html:true,placement:'right', content:"Loading..."}).popover('show')
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ajax/getitemdescription/',
                data: {id : e.data('selfid'), filter :e.data('filter')},
                statusCode: {
                         204: function() {
                         $('.popover-content:visible').html('<div>Nothing found</div>')
                         }
                },
                success: function(rply){
                $('.popover-content:visible').html(rply)
            }})
        });
```

Now if i have 4 links on my page like this

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

When i hover on link Item 1 it sends 4 POST requests. When i hover on Item 2 it sends 3 POST requests, and so on and so on. If i hover on the last link (in this case Link 4) it sends one POST request like it should.

What the heck is wrong with it? please help.

Comment: Show the code that executes this line: `$('*[data-selfid]').mouseenter(function(event) {`

Comment: Hello! i'm using twitter bootstrap and this code is executed when i hover on any of my links.

Comment: thats, not what i'm asking. What causes `$('*[data-selfid]').mouseenter` to be executed, resulting in the events being bound to `$('*[data-selfid]')`?

Comment: If the ajax is executing multiple times, you are binding to the event multiple times, likely in a loop.

Comment: Yup, silly me, you were right! my Javascript code duplicated 4 times. Thank you! :)